# Haskell FFI: How do you wrap C++ collections?

Tags: haskell, ffi, std

I have a function that returns `vector<MyClass>`; what's the best way to change this into something FFI-appropriate?

I'm thinking a type like `:: [CIntPointer]` might be a nice compromise, if possible to obtain.

Comment: Do you need to modify the individual elements on the Haskell side?

Comment: @JohnL, no, just call functions with them, e.g. `do { a <- cpp_getVector(); forM a cpp_f }` where `cpp_f :: ElementType -> IO ()`

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own C functions to alloc, free, insert, remove, etc. These functions can wrap the C++ container you want to access.
For example:

```
extern "C" {

Obj * obj_create()
{
  return new Obj();
}

void obj_destroy(Obj * schema)
{
  delete obj;
  obj = NULL;
}
...
...
}
```

then declare them in the FFI and wrap them any way you'd like.

```
data SomeObject

type Obj = Ptr SomeObject

foreign import ccall unsafe "obj_create"
    createObj :: IO Obj

foreign import ccall unsafe "obj_destroy"
    destroyObj_ :: Obj -> IO ()

foreign import ccall unsafe "&obj_destroy"
    destroyObj :: FunPtr (Obj -> IO ())
```

Some Gotchas:

1. Make sure you compile the C files with a c++ compiler(g++ instead of gcc). this will ensure that the stdc++ libs get picked up correctly.
2. Pass the library locations (-L) and libs(-lboost*) to link in when compiling the program/lib on the haskell side